# How to replace only the first node

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="column">
  <li><h2>Name</h2></li>
</ul>
<ul class="column">
  <li><h2>Address</h2></li>
</ul>
<ul class="column">
  <li><h2>Title</h2></li>
</ul>
```

How can I replace just the text between the first `<h2>` ?

I tried:

```
$(".column").first("h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

But this not works.

Any thought?

Comment: What do you mean by "not works"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to achieve it:

```
$(".column:eq(0) h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

or:

```
$(".column:first h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

Comment: All that works! Thank you guys! I needed to made a little change to have this working. `$(".column:first h2:first").html("my text");`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".column:first h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$(".column:eq(0) h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

or

```
$(".column:first h2").html("Replacing Name for another name");
```

For more details [**CHECK THIS**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)